versionlock dependencies?
I'm on Rocky Linux 8.9. I've issued the command
dnf versionlock rubygem-rdoc-6.3.3-141.module+el8.6.0+1002+a7dba0ac.noarch

There are a lot of dependencies for this package. Do I have to also versionlock the dependencies?

welcome here :) I wrote an answer, and I think it answers your question, but we might be writing better answers if you could tell us why you're versionlocking rubygem-rdoc. :)

That depends: do you want to version-lock the dependencies? DNF will not update a dependency if it means it would break rubygem-rdoc in the version you currently have. So, if your goal was to guarantee the version of rubygem-rdoc specifically, then you're done and need not do anything else.
If your purpose was to versionlock multiple package, well, you should versionlock all of them – can't really know why you are doing this :)

Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for: whether I had to versionlock the dependencies in order to avoid breaking the versionlocked package.  It's not important to me to versionlock multiple packages, just rubygem-rdoc.
